# I want to display class mega menu on hover of products

Tags: html, css

I want to display `<div class="megamenu">` on hovering of a product link, and am unable to figure it out.

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ol class="nav-primary">
        <li class="level0 nav-1 first"><a href="#" class="level0">Home</a></li>
        <li class="level0 nav-2"><a href="#" class="level0">About</a></li>
        <li class="level0 nav-3" id="products"><a href="#" class="level0 products">Products</a>
        <li class="level0 nav-4"><a href="#" class="level0">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="level0 nav-5"><a href="#" class="level0">Service</a></li>
        <li class="level0 nav-6 last"><a href="#" class="level0">Contact Us'</a></li> 
    </ol>
</nav>
<div class="megamenu">This is for test</div></li>
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS given the current HTML structure.

Comment: The closest thing you can do is display megamenu on hover of the entire nav. Hovering on a product link to display megamenu would require a more powerful selector than currently exists in CSS.

Comment: As mentioned above, there aren't any CSS solutions for this as yet. If you still need a solution for this, then you need to look at javaScript/jQuery. That would definitely provide you your much needed solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only CSS is not possible (at least not right now). If .megamenu were inside every li, then you could use CSS. But for this particular case where .megamenu is not a child of .nav-primary, you could use jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav .nav-primary a').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.megamenu').show();
  });
  $('#nav .nav-primary a').mouseleave(function() {      
    $('.megamenu').hide();
  });
});
```

You can see this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zxfb8gxL/